# Smart Fox Server events not being fired in Xamarin Android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, smartfoxserver

I am Working on Xamarin Android Project which uses smart fox server.

And I am writing my business logic in PCL(Portable Class Library)

The following events fire properly with console application.

`smartFox.AddEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION, OnConnection);`
`smartFox.AddEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION_LOST, OnConnectionLost);`;

.
.
.
`smartFox.AddEventListener(SFSEvent.CONNECTION_RESUME, OnConnectionResume);`

But, Events like OnConnection,OnConnection,OnConnectionResume are not fired in Android Emulator